# How to get Registration ID of device which is sending messages using GCM in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, chat

I am developing a chat application in android using GCM.

I am able to send messages successfully from one device and receive notifications on other device.

But I want to find out the registration ID of the device which is sending the messages in order to identify the sender.

For example:
Device A sends Message to Device B.
Now Person B receives the message but does not know the sender, How can I find the Registration ID of Device A on Device B?

How can I achieve it?

Comment: you can send it as message to the other device

Comment: By using this you will find the reg_id for the particular device.. final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

Comment: Sorry I guess the question was not clear. I have edited the question.

Comment: Each device have its own unique registration id..so its simple to figure out with that.

Comment: Notifications can be in JSON so you can pass additional data that you do not show the user who receives the message.

Comment: @TTransmit .. Thanks. I tried it.. Successful.. :D